# how to change high-lighting color for python #comment in Vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I use this script to find out the group of #comment

```
nmap <C-S-P> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
    return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

and it shows the high-light group is "pythonComment". Then where should I change the color for "pythonComment"? The default comment color is too dark in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
:hi link pythonComment Operator
```

Or

```
:hi pythonComment ctermfg=2 gui=italic guifg=#408010
```

Change the color code to whatever you like.

Comment: It's not working.. I ran the second command and the # comments become the same color as ordianary word(white).